# Split Eloquent collection into multiple arrays based on property name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-charts

I'm creating a graph using Laravel Charts and I'm getting the columns (time periods) and the dataset from an Eloquent query.

My query returns an array like the following:

| Period | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 01/21 | 200.00 |
| 02/21 | 150.00 |
| 03/21 | 175.00 |
| ... | ... |

Laravel Charts require you to input an array for the chart label and an array for the chart values. Currently, I create and populate the arrays in this manner:

```php
//the function getData returns the table above as an Eloquent Collection
$form_data = $this->getData($initial_date, $final_date, $product_list, $group);
$labels = [];
$dataset = [];
foreach ($form_data as $data) {
    array_push($labels, $data->period);
    array_push($dataset, $data->amount);
}
$chart->labels($labels);
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', $dataset);
```

Is there a "more native" way of doing this?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. Where's the eloquent query?

Comment: @Rwd you assumed correctly, 5.4.

Comment: @Bennett Sorry, my variable names weren't the best since it was only a local test yet. but the query is being made in the getData function. It's result is the table in the questoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Laravel >=5.4, one option would be to make use of [Higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages) with collections e.g.

```
$form_data->map->period->toArray()
```

This would mean you code would look something like:

```
$form_data = $this->getData($initial_date, $final_date, $product_list, $group);

$chart->labels($form_data->map->period->toArray());
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', $form_data->map->amount->toArray());
```

Alternatively, (as mentioned in the comments) you could also use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck):

```
$form_data = $this->getData($initial_date, $final_date, $product_list, $group);

$chart->labels($form_data->pluck('period')->toArray());
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', $form_data->pluck('amount')->toArray());
```

Comment: Why not just use `$form_data->pluck('period')` instead of `$form_data->map->period` which would be more intuitive?

Comment: @shaedrich That's a very good point! I genuinely don't know why I didn't think of that. Since it looks like the chart methods only accept an array, the OP would still need to call `toArray()`.

Comment: Sure, that works with pluck as well. I bet, since pluck might probably be just a shortcut for map, they are just two sides of the same coin. Thanks to you, I learned about higher order collection methods in Laravel today :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data_get()` if you want to do the same thing with less lines.

```php
$form_data = $this->getData($initial_date, $final_date, $product_list, $group);

$chart->labels(data_get($form_data, '*.period');
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', data_get($form_data, '*.amount'));
```

[`data_get($target, $key, $default = null)`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-data-get) works with simple objects, arrays and even Collections and returns an array. It's been in the framework since 5.5 version.

Comment: Hey, it worked, thanks. Do you know if I can tag two answers as correct?